# Section(s) of tangent bundle of a quadric hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(\mathcal Q_{n}, H) \subset \mathbb P^{n+1}$ be a smooth polarized quadric hypersurface with $n \geq 3$ and the sectional genus $g=\frac{K_X.H^{n-1}+(n-1).H^n}{2} \geq 2$. Then is it true that $H^0(T_{\mathcal Q_{n}}) \neq 0$?

One can rewrite the tangent bundle $T_{\mathcal Q_{n}}$ as $\wedge^{n-1} \Omega_{{\mathcal Q_{n}}} \otimes \mathcal O_{{\mathcal Q_{n}}}(2H)$. But why the global sections of the later should be nonzero?

Comment: @Damian Rossier, thanks. However I wanted to ask for the situation $n \geq 3$. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: There was a technical glitch here. I was just correcting my comment. If it has genus $0$ then there are non zero global sections (the space is three dimensional). I will get back to this in a moment.

Comment: @DamianRössler, again in my case the sectional genus is atleast $2$. However I didn't think that $H^0(T_X)$ will depend on that. I have further edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write $m:=n+1$ and I suppose that $n\geq 2$. Let $H$ be the smooth quadric hypersurface.
Write $T_{V}$ for the tangent bundle of a smooth variety $V.$

There are two canonical exact sequences on ${\bf P}^m=P$:
$$
0\to {\cal O}_P(-2)\to {\cal O}_P\to {\cal O}_H\to 0\,\,\,\,(\ast)
$$
and
$$
0\to {\cal O}\to {\cal O}_P(1)^{\oplus(m+1)}\to T_P\to 0\,\,\,\,(\ast\ast)
$$
and there is an exact sequence on $H$
$$
0\to T_H\to T_P|_H\to N_{H/P}={\cal O}_P(2)|_H\to 0\,\,\,\,(\ast\ast\ast)
$$
where the identification of line bundles  is given by the adjunction formula. Now
we have the formula
$$
\dim(H^0(P,{\cal O}_P(k)))={(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+m)\over m!}
$$
if $k\geq -m$ (see Ravi Vakil's notes, 18.4). Using the long exact cohomology sequence of $(\ast)$ and  the fact that line bundles on projective space only have cohomology in
$H^0$ and $H^m$, we see that
$$
\dim(H^0(P,{\cal O}_P(k)|_H))=\dim(H^0(P,{\cal O}_P(k)))-\dim(H^0(P,{\cal O}_P(k-2)))
$$
$$={(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+m)-(k-1)k\cdots (k+m-2)\over m!}
$$
if $k\geq 2-m$ and also that $H^1(H,{\cal O}_H)=0$.

Hence if we restrict $(\ast\ast)$ to $H$ and use the long exact cohomology sequence again, we get that
$$
\dim(H^0(H,T_P|_H))=(m+1)^2-1
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\dim(H^0(H,N_{H/P}))=\dim(H^0(H,{\cal O}_P(2)|_H))=(m+1)(m+2)/2-1
$$
Since the polynomial $$((x+1)^2-1)-((x+1)(x+2)/2-1)=(x^2+x)/2$$ is strictly positive for $x>0$, we thus see by considering
the exact sequence
$$
0\to H^0(H,T_H)\to H^0(H,T_P|_H)\to H^0(H,N_{H/P})
$$
obtained from $(\ast\ast\ast)$
that $H^0(H,T_H)\not=0.$ In fact we have $\dim(H^0(H,T_H))\geq (m^2+m)/2.$

Comment: thanks for the answer. Are you taking the polarization to be $\mathcal O_{\mathcal Q_n}(1)$ i.e. the genus zero case?  (or is it independent of polarization?)

Comment: @New. What do you mean by "polarization" (of a hypersurface)?

Comment: I consider a quadric hypersurface to be the zero scheme of a section of ${\cal O}_P(2)$.